# Spring MVC dynamic list form submit

Tags: java, html, forms, spring-mvc

I have two POJOs used for an html form submit. One is a wrapper to wrap an `ArrayList`.

```
public Class Schedule {
    private List<Course> courses;
    // Getter & Setters for courses
}

public Class Course {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    // Getter & Setters for both variables
}
```

So when a user navigates to a specific Schedule webpage it'll look through the courses and display them as editable text fields

```
<form method="post">
   <c:forEach var="course" varStatus="status" items="${schedule.courses}>
       <div id="${course.id}">
           <input type="text" value="${course.name} name="course[${status.index}].name" />
           <input type="text" value="${course.description} name="course[${status.index}].description" />
           <input type="button" value="Delete"/>
       </div>
   </c:forEach>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And I have javascript to delete a specific course from the view when they click the delete button which I won't list out.

Say I'm displaying 3 courses and I decide to delete the middle one. The two courses left over on submit will be posted as `course.[0].name/course.[0].description` and `course[2].name/course[2].description` and when spring populates the schedule object for the courses, the second index in the `ArrayList` will be a Course object with all values set to null.

I was wondering how I can prevent that from happening. Can Spring filter that out for me or do I have to do it myself in the controller?

Thanks.

So my post request looks like this:
    
     `courses[0].name = "course 1"
     courses[0].description = "description for course 1"
     courses[2].name = "course 3"
     courses[2].description = "description for courses 3"`

But what Spring populates for me in the ArrayList is 3 Course objects, the second one in the array list being a course object with both name and description set to null.

Comment: what will happen when while deleting (in JS) you also "recompute" indexes, i.e. you would have only course[0] and course[1] afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to help Spring do it on the Controller.When the form is sent it should send something like:

[{"name" :name,"description":description}, 2nd object here]

to the Controller method with the mapping of the form post URL.

It's possible to have the controller method automatically map the above to an object via @ModelAttribute and your Schedule object. Spring wont care about the gap of index because it will only care the object is correctly sent to build it ie how you send a course object.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using ModelAttribute to map it. I just don't like the fact that when I do have a gap and send it to Spring that Spring represents the gap as an instantiated object with all the properties in the object null. I just want Spring to not even include that object.

Comment: that would only happen if you didn't fully delete the corresponding div in your JSP file  before sending it.Spring cant map something that doesnt exist.It's mapping null for you because the object /div is still in the form when its sent so its being mapped.

Comment: I checked the post request an it is posting this data: 
    `courses[0].name = "course 1"
     courses[0].description = "description for course 1"
     courses[2].name = "course 3"
     courses[2].description = "description for courses 3"`

but still my array list has 3 objects